# Azure functions and entity framework

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using azure function with lot of tables. for every create , delete, update, and other operation do I need to create one function for everything. So in that case I will end up with hundreds of endpoints. In case i have 100 tables
I was thinking to pass function name in URL but then how to call it.

Can I do

```
 [FunctionName("Account")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Account(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "account/{functionName}")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            string functionName
          )
        {
            try
            {
                log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
```

based on `functionName` variable I will call appropriate method.
But this will be like hardcoded if `functionName` is  addaccount then call Addmethod and likewise

Am i right??

Answer (score 0):

This is a feasible method (put the string in the route, and then get this value in the function declaration section), and you can also choose to write the string parameter in the request, and then you can get this inside your function parameter. Both methods are feasible.